# how to do batch shorthand loop for large arrays?

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops

hi I'm new to doing batch scripts so my code is simple.
I know you should use a for loop to iterate over an arrays contents but I saw a shorthand method that retrieves the contents with indexes between the specified range like so :

```
array[1-7]
```

and it works but when you use two digit numbers it runs into problems.
what am I doing wrong here?
appreciate your help :)

Comment: Try `$array[0..12]`.  [Range operator ..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#range-operator-)  `$array = [char[]](65..90); $array[0..25]`

Comment: To compliment Daniels comment, you can also use a comma for specific index values `[0,1,7,34]`. **Note:** *arrays begin at 0, not 1*. Also, you mentioned batch files, which are typically refered to when using cmd cli commands. What we've suggested is Powershell related, not *"batch"*.

Comment: batch has no concept of arrays. The only variable type is STRING. You can use the naming syntax of arrays, but in the end, it's just a bunch of similar named but independent variables. All array-related processing has to be done by code. Messy, but doable.

Comment: you say BATCH, but you seem to be working with POWERSHELL ... which are you actually concerned with?